# OSX Objective C BOOL/vars thread safe?

Tags: macos, thread-safety

Simple Question... is a global BOOL thread safe for me to use for thread synchronization?
What other data types are actually safe, e.g. long longs..?

Eg:
I have a task that runs - only want it to run once concurrently.

```
<pre>
BOOL isRunning;
unsigned long long progress;

if(!isRunning){
            dispatch_async(secondaryTask,^{
            [self doWork];
        });

-(void)doWork
{
isRunning=TRUE;
do a long op
isRunning=FALSE;
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the atomic types, exactly the same rules as ordinary C apply. So there's no guarantee of thread safety on any of them.

Use OSAtomic, `NSConditionLock`, the `NSLocking` protocol, serial dispatch queues, individual runloops, memory fences, spin locks, etc, to achieve thread safety.

For the trivial code given, which I accept is probably just for exposition, you'd most likely provide a completion handler block, which the asynchronous block would dispatch upon completion. If it's a serial queue, just push the task to it. Consider a dispatch group if you want synchronisation points within concurrent task groups.